# How to Convert Image Array which is coming from Active Directory to Python to Save in the Drive?

Tags: python, image

I am getting a array of :

```
255 216 255 224 0 16 74 70 73 70 0 1 1 1 0 96 0 96 0 0 255 219 0 67 0
8 6 6 7 6 5 8 7 7 7 9 9 8 10 12 20 13 12 11 11 12 25 18 19 15 20 29 26
31 30 29 26 28 28 32 36 46 39 32 34 44 35 28 28 40 55 41 44 48 49 52 52
52 31 39 57 61 56 50 60 46 51 52 50 255 219 0 67 1 9 9 9 12 11 12 24 13 
13 24 50 33 28 33 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 
50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 
50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 255 192 0 17 8 0 135 0 105 3 1 34 0 2 17 1 3 17 1
255 196 0 31 0 0 1 5 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
11 255 196 0 181 16 0 2 1 3 3 2 4 3 5 5 4 4 0 0 1 125 1 2 3 0 4 17 5 18 33 
49 65 6 19 81 97 7 34 113 20 50 129 145 161 8 35 66 177 193 21 82 209 240
36 51 98 114 130 9 10 22 23 24 25 26 37 38 39 40 41 42 52 53 54 55 56 57
58 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 99 100 101 102 103 
104 105 106 115 116 117 118 119 120 121 122 131 132 133 134 135 136 137
138 146 147 148 149 150 151 152 153 154 162 163 164 165 166 167 168 169
170 178 179 18
```

in my arguments say "`ProfileImageName`" and i want to convert this to Image byte array and save the `File` in the drive.

Comment: Please format your question properly.

Comment: Can you show what image you're expect?